# Convert JSON to CSV but each json object should be contained in one row

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I want to convert my json file which has multiple jsons into a csv such that each json is in one column. I don't want to convert it such that each field in json is a seperate column. So there will be only one column and the entire json object is stored as string in it.

Sample JSON file:

```
[ {"Name" : "abcd","Id" : "123"} , {"Name" : "efgh","Id" : "124"} ]
```

Sample csv :

| Data |
| --- |
| "Name" : "abcd","Id" : "123" |
| "Name" : "efgh","Id" : "124" |

Comment: What have you tried? You should start by just printing each element to the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
import pandas as pd
js = [ {"Name" : "abcd","Id" : "123"} , {"Name" : "efgh","Id" : "124"} ] 
df = pd.DataFrame([str(x) for x in js], columns = ['data'])
```

output:

[image]